# Should I scan infected Windows files before moving them to a Linux machine?

Tags: linux-mint

My friend's laptop is running Windows. His laptop has infected (spyware, trojan, virus etc). He wants to install linux mint.

First he wants to copy his files from Windows in external device. After the installation of Linux Mint in his laptop he wants to move all his files from external device to his laptop. Do I need to scan the files before move the files to the Linux environment?

Comment: If you're worried, then just scan them.

Comment: Yes but how? I mean I will move the files from infected laptop to the usb then I will scan the  usb from infected laptop. After I will install linux mint and last I will scan usb from linux mint. Is it correct way?

Comment: Install Mint, install some AV, hook up drive, scan files on drive.

Comment: Yes but is it good idea to scan usb first from infected windows enviroment? In linux  are there only av programs? Are any antimalware programs? I think that there are some rare infections that can infect both linux and windows.

Comment: No, scanning from an infected computer is useless, as active  infections could just fake out the scanner and make it think the files are clean. As for which software is available in Linux to do the task, use Google to locate a few options.

Comment: If I scan from infected windows system a usb or my hard drive will the infection spread faster in hard drive or usb?

Answer (score -2):

Not necessarily, viruses usually place them selves bound to a fake process it cooked up or some system files. You should always scan them just in case, but i do not think it would be necessary. Another thing to note is the files you bring over to Linux may not even be compatible to be opened. (exe's [unless you install wine, but even then wine isn't perfect..], and other window install files)

So should you scan them just to be safe?
Probably.. It doesn't take long.